# Smallest integer whose first n multiples contain the digit 1

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

For some time now I have been investigating the function $M(n)$, the least integer such that the first $n$ multiples of $M(n)$ contain the digit $1$. Thus $M(3) = 51$, because $51$ is the smallest integer whose first $3$ multiples all contain the digit $1$: $51, 102, 153$. Here then are three questions to ponder:

a) Without a computer, determine $M(10)$.

b) With a computer, if necessary, find $M(100)$.

c) Find bounds for the value of $M(n)$ in general.

Comment: Requesting to be moved to Math Stack Exchange because it's a math problem.

Comment: What counts as a "solution" to (c)? I don't see how (c) could be definitively answered. These seem like some questions you have, but not really a puzzle that can be solved.

Comment: @Deusovi Guess you've never tried crowd-sourcing a thesis paper. xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doesn't look like anyone has answered the "no computers" part yet, so I will do that.

First, a simple observation:

> The number must contain the digit "1", since it is its own first multiple

That also means:

> M(10) = M(9) Since M(10) * 10 is just putting an extra zero on the back of the original number, which already contains a "1"

This has an important consequence:

> $n$ is going to be at most 9, which means a digit times $n$ is at most going to be a two digit number.

I'm going to call the most significant digit from such a multiplication the "carry" from here on, and the least significant digit "LSD".

Single digit multiplication has an interesting property:

> The carry is at most $n - 1$

This even holds for multiplying a many-digit number with a single digit number, which is what we are doing.

Reformulation of problem in these new terms:

> Since in a multiplication the carry from the previous digit is added to the LSD of the next, we need to assure this sum is 1 at least somewhere in the number for $n$ from 1 to 9.

We can also get back the original observation from this:

> Since we don't get a carry for $n = 1$, the number must contain a digit that has a LSD of 1 when multiplied by 1. There's only one such digit.

## What follows is establishing an explicit upper bound. Skip to part 2 if that's boring

But now it's more general! What about $n = 2$?

> The carry is at most 1, so either we need a digit with an LSD of 1 after multiplying with 2, which isn't possible since we can only get even numbers, or the LSD must be 0 and the carry from the previous number must be 1.

There are two such digits:

> 0 and 5

In the case of $n = 3$:

> carry = 0 AND LSD = 1 --> 7, carry = 1 AND LSD = 0 --> 0, carry = 2 AND LSD = 9 --> 3

And in the case of $n = 4$:

> carry = 0 AND LSD = 1 --> no, carry = 1 AND LSD = 0 --> 0 or 5, carry = 2 AND LSD = 9 --> no, carry = 3 AND LSD = 8 --> 2 or 7

Now, let me stop there, because we have another wonderful digit, the number 2:

> $2n$ produces a carry of 1 for all $n$ from 5 to 9

Some care must be taken though:

> The digit more significant than 2 must be zero for this to work, or 2 must be the most significant digit of the number

Furthermore:

> The LSD of 2 is high for $n = 9$ (more specifically 8). Which means the digit that follows 2 can be no higher than 2 for this trick to work. (or the high $n$ values must produce a 1 somewhere else. For instance, if the carry is 3, we still get a nice 1. That would work if the following digit is 3)

Since this greatly simplifies the calculation, I'm going to be bold and assume:

> That the most significant digit is 2.

I will deal with this assumption later.

From the $n$ values not covered by 2, we have the following set of possibilities:

> (1),(0,5),(0,3,7),(0,2,5,7) [not in order!]

But some of them could possibly be served by the same digit. Let's check that:

> For 0 to serve both the second and third set, the following it must produce a carry of 1 for both $n = 2$ and $n = 3$ Thats 5 to 9 in the first case, and 3 to 6 in the second case (the 3 is there since we could get a carry from the LSD + carry sum of the following digit). Anyway, the overlap is just the digits 5 and 6.

That means:

> 0 followed by either 5 or 6 solves both $n = 2$ and $n = 3$

We can also see that one of these

> the 5

Overlaps with the fourth set. The digit following that must produce a carry of 1 for $n = 4$ which means:

> either 3 or 4.

Since we have covered all $n$ values then, we can take the lowest one to minimize the number.

We then have the partial string:

> 053

Combining this with the digit "1" after the leading 2 can be done in just two ways, one of which is smaller:

> 20531

From the carry requirements of the earlier sets, this must also be the smallest 5 digit number with this property, of those starting with a "2" that is. There may still be a lower number of digits required, or there is a 5 digit number that starts with 1.

## Part 2, finding M(10)

M(10) must contain:

> A "1"

> Either "0" or "5", followed by a digit 5-9, in order to make a "1" when doubled

> An even number, followed by "2" or "3", in order to make a "1" when multiplied by 5.

That's five digits. But:

> "An even number" and "digit 5-9" could be the same, either "6" or "8"

So in the 4 digit case, we have the fragment:

> (0|5)(6|8)(2|3)

With the "1" either before or after it. That's just 16 possibilities, so we can check them all:

> 1062, 1063, 1082, 1083, 1562, 1563, 1582, 1583, 0621, 0631, 0821, 0831, 5621, 5631, 5821, 5831

But if you multiply them all by 4, none of them contain a "1".

That's all the 4 digit solutions out of the way. Since we have our upper bound of:

> 20000

The first digit must then be a "1".

Using the fragments from before, there are "just" 280 numbers to check, but we can do better.

$n = 4$ is a bit contrieved, but it's usable to filter out a lot of these:

> No number multiplied by 4 has "1" as the LSD, so it must come from a carry, which can be either 1, 2 or 3.

For a carry of 1:

> The LSD must be 0, which can come from only 0 or 5. The 1 carry can only come from a 2 (via chained carry), 3 or 4.

For a carry of 2:

> The LSD must be 9, which is impossible

For a carry of 3:

> The LSD must be 8, which can com from only 2 or 7, The 3 carry can only from from a 7 (via chained carry), 8 or 9

For the (0|5)(6|8)(2|3) group, we have a free digit. How does that fit with the first one (02|03|04|52|53|54)?

> Not at all.

What about (27|28|29|77|78|79)?

> Possibly at the end

We then have:

> 1(0|5)(6|8)2(7|8|9)

But since the (7|8|9) group is at the end we have no chained carry, so 7 is not possible

That's just these 8 numbers:

> 10628, 10629, 10828, 10829, 15628, 15629, 15828, 15829

But only the first two survive being multiplied by 3, and neither works when multiplying by 6.

Then there's the original groups remaining:

> 1(0|5)(5|6|7|8|9)(0|2|4|6|8)(2|3) or 1(0|2|4|6|8)(2|3)(0|5)(5|6|7|8|9)

That's 200 numbers, but here too we can use $n = 4$.

For the first group and (02|03|04|52|53|54):

> 1(0|5)54(2|3) => 10542, 10543, 15542, 15543

But none of those survive multiplication by 6.

We also have:

> 1(0|5)(5|6|7|8|9)03 => 10503, 10603, 10703, 10803, 10903, 15503, 15603, 15703, 15803, 15903

Of those, these 4 survive multiplication by 3:

> 10503, 10603, 10703, 15703

In fact, the last one survives all $n$ up to 10.

For the first group and (27|28|29|77|78|79):

> 1(0|5)78(2|3) => 10782, 10783, 15782, 15783

But none of those survive multiplication by 3.

We only have the second permutation of the original groups left. Since we have already found a lower candidate for M(10), it has now shrunk to:

> 1(0|2|4)(2|3)(0|5)(5|6|7|8|9)

We can now try to fit it with (02|03|04|52|53|54):

> 10(2|3)(0|5)(5|6|7|8|9) => 10205, 10206, 10207, 10208, 10209, 10255, 10256, 10257, 10258, 10259, 10305, 10306, 10307, 10308, 10309, 10355, 10356, 10357, 10358, 10359

Five of those go away since we need chained carry, the rest when multiplying by 8.

And finally, we can fit it with (27|28|29|77|78|79)

> which does in fact not fit at all.

As the number:

> 15703

Is the only one below 20000, it must also be the smallest, and therefore be M(10)

---

## Part b), finding M(100), computers allowed

Just to see if this was sufficient, I tried checking every number:

```
let number = 1
while(true){
    let found = true
    for(let j=1; j <= 100; j++){
        if(!((number*j) + "").includes(1)){
            found = false
            break
        }
    }
    if(found){
        console.log(number)
        break
    }
    number++    
}
```

After a minute on a laptop, it spits out the answer:

> 134003006

So I think a higher value than 100 is required to force more creative approaches.

---

## part c), a bound

[Sjoerd's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98151/smallest-integer-whose-first-n-multiples-contain-the-digit-1/98185#98185)  has a very nice idea, but I would like to point out that rather than:

> 1 000...[length of n zeroes]...000 2 000... [length of n zeroes] ...000 3 000... [length of n zeroes] ...000 5

One could instead do:

> 2 000...[length of n - 1 zeroes]...000 1 000... [length of n zeroes] ...000 3 000... [length of n zeroes] ...000 5

Since 1 never causes an overflow. This bound is approximately 5 times smaller.

And actually, it's beneficial to move the 1 all the way to the back, since more zeroes early makes the number smaller:

> 2 000...[length of n zeroes]...000 3 000... [length of n zeroes] ...000 5 000... [length of n - 1 zeroes] ...000 1

Though the gain is extremely small.

But this idea opens for a generalization where we can special case some large classes of numbers:

If the number starts with:

> a "1"

Then we can

> use the original construction, but with a zero removed everywhere.

On the other hand, if it starts with:

> 2-3(0|1|2|3)...

Then

> Only the "...0005" may overflow, so we put it in front and remove a zero everywhere else

Finally, if it starts with:

> >3(0|1|2|3)... or "4", then we put 0003 and 0005 in front, leaving 1 and 2 in the back

Only if the number starts with

> 5-9

We have to use the worst case strategy.

Two of the strategies above actually reach a little bit further:

> If the digit following the leading digit is a "0", the rest of the number has space to overflow internally. This stretches two of the bounds up to 219(9...) and 519(9...)

Comment: Nice improvement to part c!

Comment: @Sjoerd It's almost possible to move the 5 before the 3 too, and remove another 0, but that only works for even numbers.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to b) is

> 134003006

Proof:

> [OEIS says so.](http://oeis.org/A039932/)

Comment: Wow! That also gives you question a). I should definitely get the habit to check for this website!

Comment: I wasn't allowed to use a computer for a) :P

Comment: Haha, well pointed out!

Answer (score 8):

An answer to c:

For M(100), the following construction would create a crude but simple upper bound:

> Consider a number of the form "00x,00y,00z". Those units of the form "00x" will never create an overflow to the next unit for the multiples under consideration. 
>  * For multiples between 10 and 19, the unit "001" always produces a one 
>  * For multiples between 20 and 39, the unit "005" always produces an one
>  * For multiples between 40 and 66, the unit "003" always produces an one
>  * for multiples between 67 and 99, the unit "002" always produces an one
>  * for multiples between 01 and 09, those are also covered by the above
>  Together, the number "1,002,003,005" works for M(99).
>  In fact, due to the starting 1, it works up to M(199).
>  M(200) would create a one by the last 005 as the overflow stays a one.
>  In fact, 1,002,003,005 works for 201, 202, 203, and a few more as well, but I'm not sure how well that generalizes.

This generalizes to a formula:

> $M(n) < 10^{1 + 3\lceil \log_{10}{n/2}\rceil}< Cn^3$, where $C < 10,000$

There must be tighter upper bounds.

Comment: Help with formatting is appreciated. I don't know how to combine ">!" and other auto-formatting, so had to rely on <p> and manual formatting.

Answer (score 5):

As I'm familiar with programming, I only could do question a) with a computer.

> Hopefully this could help someone determine $M(10)$ without computers or determine $M(100)$! I only did a brute force algorithm.

[Julia](https://julialang.org/) program

> I took a screenshot of the code, for syntax highlighting[image]

---

> ```
>  function M(n)
>      """
>          Smallest integer whose first n multiples contain the digit 1
>      """
>      multiples = Vector{Int}() # We will here store all first n multiples of n
>      number_correct_multiples = 0 # Use to count multiples that have 1 in their digits
>      current_int = n # Use to know which is current_int tested as a potential solution
>      current_multiple = 2*n # Use to know which current multiple is being tested
>      while number_correct_multiples != n
>          current_multiple = current_int
>          multiples = Vector{Int}()
>          while length(multiples) != n
>              if current_multiple%current_int == 0
>                  append!(multiples, current_multiple)
>              end
>              current_multiple += 1
>          end
>          number_correct_multiples = sum([1 in digits(i) for i in multiples])
>          current_int += 1
>      end
>      @show multiples
>      return current_int-1
>  end
> ```

---

> M(3) shows `[51, 102, 153]` and returns 51
>  M(10) shows `[15703, 31406, 47109, 62812, 78515, 94218, 109921, 125624, 141327, 157030]` and returns 15703
>  I could run into some meta-heuristics to find a bound on $M(100)$ but I'd do it later